# Github Repository sharing

Tags: github, github-pages

I recently started using github, and me and some of my friends are working on a website
We want to implement it using gihubpages, I am wondering if there is a way to share the repository , i know we can have multiple users accessing and editing the repository ,
I am asking if there is way such that the repository will be available for members like their own repository, but if one changes in theirs all else will also be changed, so its not like that's just really a single users but everyones.
So I am asking if there is way to create a shared repository like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally opt to make all people who edit the website a contributor and put the repository any of your personal accounts. That's the simplest way to collaborate.

If needed you could [create a free organization on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/creating-a-new-organization-from-scratch) and put the repository in there, that way it's clear that the repo is owned by the group and nod just a person. [More information on organizations can be found in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/about-organizations).

If you want a personal copy to work in, then team members can either work on a personal branch in the shared repo. Or they can fork the shared repo into their personal accounts.

There is no automated way to keep these forks in sync - it they need to be the same, why not work on the shared repo to begin with - but there are a number of sync features that help you sync. You can propose changes to she main repo using Pull Requests through the <kbd>Contribute</kbd> button (as you can when people are working on their own branch) and you can sync the changes to each fork with the <kbd>Fetch Upstream</kbd>

If you wanted to, you could automate some of that [syncing using GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=sync%20repo%20).

[image]